# converting output from string to integer

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to programm a small tool which merges some files on a unix server. I am now forced to merge 20 files into 1. all of those files contain a header and trailer, which needs to be removed and the new created file needs to have a header and trailer. header and trailer are a bit tricky for me to create (the have to be excatly 334 chars none more none less). I was able to create everything but the trailer. the special thing is that the trailer should contain to number of lines.

I have set up my small tool like this:

```
//loop to cat all 20 files (remove header and trailer)
//generate header from date 
//execute wc -l on generated file and add +1 (bc trailer is missing)
//append trailer with executed  wc -l information in it
```

I have tried several commands to add +1 to my trailer but none of them worked properly:

This is what I worked out up to now:

```
lineCount=echo more someFile.dat | wc -l
echo $lineCount
//echo "$((lineCount + 1))" -> 1
//echo "$(($lineCount + 1))" -> 1
//let "lineCount+=1" -> 1
//$lineCount=lineCount+1 -> won't work
//$lineCount=$lineCount+1 -> won't work
//x=$lineCount+1 -> won't work
```

This was the output of echo `$lineCount` (without any changes or anything) there seem to be two empty spaces before the number

```
163108
```

What my goal was that instead of `163108` the number should be `163109`

edit:

my input files look something like this:

```
HFFP20190         *
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQWERSTUVWXYZ                            ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASD
TFFP2019000031795 *
```

whereas HFFP is the header and TFFP is the trailer -> the main difference between header and trailer is the last number (31795), which contains the number of rows in the file. The output after this merge should be something like this:

```
HFFP20190         *
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQWERSTUVWXYZ                            ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASD
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQWERSTUVWXYZ                            ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASD
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQWERSTUVWXYZ                            ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASD

...
TFFP2019000163109 *
```

Comment: i am aware that those double slashes are not comments and the syntax is not correct but i had some formatting issues that's why i replaced the # with //

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: one moment - i am setting something together

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# get only the lines from wc command
lineCount=$(wc -l someFile.dat | cut -d' ' -f1)

# add 1
((lineCount++))

echo "$lineCount"
```

Comment: You can replace `wc -l someFile.dat | cut -d' ' -f1` with `wc -l < someFile.dat `

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
lineCount=echo
```

assigns the string "echo" to the variable. In full,

```
lineCount=echo more someFile.dat | wc -l
```

runs the command

```
more someFile.dat | wc -l
```

with output to standard output, not to your variable, while *temporarily* assigning `lineCount="echo"` for just the duration of this single command.

For the record, the syntax to capture standard output to the variable is

```
lineCount=$(wc -l <someFile.dat)
```

where I have factored out the useless `more` and the even more useless `echo`.

On the whole, a much better solution is probably to refactor all of this into an Awk script. You haven't described the header and footer logic in enough detail, but something like

```
awk '
    # Skip first line in all files except the first
    FNR==1 && NR>1 { next }
    # Print and increment, excluding trailer
    !/^TFFP/ { print; c++ }
    # Add back last trailer
    END { sub(/000[1-9][0-9]*$/, "000" 1+c); print} ' someFiles*
```

The wildcard `someFiles*` will need to be replaced with something which actually matches your input files in the right order; perhaps `*.dat`?